# How to add AI based suggestions in android custom keyboard app

Tags: android-studio, input, nlp, custom-keyboard, search-suggestion

I'm trying to develop custom android keyboard app. I have seen many examples on Github. Building a keyboard is not a problem but adding AI based suggestions is a problem and I could not find any good example for implementing AI based suggestions in keyboard app. Any solution, help or example by following best practices?

I tried many Github projects but they are too olds.